# Why is Sequelize addAssociations not working?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to associate post with tags. But sequelize generates wrong sql query.

Sequelize v4.27.36

```
let post = await models.Post.findByPk(req.params.id, { paranoid:false });

if (req.body.tags) {
   post = await post.addTags(req.body.tags);
}
```

But it's returning an error:

```
"code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
"errno": 1064,
"sqlState": "42000",
"sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `post_tag` AS `PostTag` WHERE `PostTag`.`PostId` = 89 AND `PostTag`.`TagId`' at line 1",
"sql": "SELECT  FROM `post_tag` AS `PostTag` WHERE `PostTag`.`PostId` = 89 AND `PostTag`.`TagId` IN (1, 2);"
```

There is no * after SELECT.

Comment: You need to specify `attribute` on the second param object, no? That's to specify the columns you want to return.

Comment: @MazBeye hm.I thought it should work by default. I've tried to add `{through: {attributes: ['*']}}`. Now I have something like this `post = await post.setTags(req.body.tags, {attributes:['*']});`

Comment: @MazBeye It works but not correct. It's duplicating records in junction table. It produces queries like this `SELECT * FROM 'post_tag' AS 'PostTag' WHERE 'PostTag'.'PostId' = 89;
 DELETE FROM 'post_tag' WHERE 'PostId' = 89 AND 'TagId' IN (NULL, NULL)
 INSERT INTO 'post_tag' ('PostId','TagId') VALUES (89,1),(89,2);` And now I have duplicated associations in the table. That's because of wrong DELETE query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I,ve found out that I have to capitalize attributes

```
post = await post.setTags(req.body.tags, {attributes: ['PostId', 'TagId']});
```

It's working fine now